# Rails, date search query from a datetime field. Why this one does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new in this world of Rails, so sorry if the mistake is too obvious.

I am building a search form. I managed to compare strings. However I am struggling with dates.

This is in the form:

```
= select_datetime Date.today, :prefix => :search_start_date
```

This is the query I am trying  (note:start_date in a valid column in Events)

```
 @events = @events.where("start_date > ?", "%#{params[:search_start_date]}%")
```

Because one is a date and the other a datetime I though I had to cast them. However nothing I have tried have worked.

Any suggestions?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your params in a Time object :

```
@time = Time.new(params[:search_start_date][:year], params[:search_start_date][:month],params[:search_start_date][:day] , params[:search_start_date][:hour], params[:search_start_date][:minute])
@events = Event.where("start_date > ?", @time)
```

It should work. However you should set start_date with a datetime type. Indeed If you have an event with the date April 17, 2012 and you are looking for @events started after April 17, 2012 at 9:00 the event will not displayed. Only event starting the April 18 and after will be displayed.

Comment: This works pretty well. 
Using the example you made, if I type in the search 17 April 2012, it retrieves all the events from that same day.

Comment: Good to know! Finally what solution have you adopted?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this it give you better results

```
 @time = params[:search_start_date]+" "+"00:00:00"

 @events = @events.where("start_date > ?", @time)
```

Try it and it give you reult with time greater than 00:00:00

Comment: I throws this error. undefined method `+' for {"day"=>"17", "month"=>"4", "year"=>"2012"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parse :

```
 @events = @events.where("start_date > ?", "%#{Date.parse(params[:search_start_date])}%") if !params[:search_start_date].nil?
```

Comment: mmmh... that throws this error. undefined method `gsub!' for {"day"=>"18", "month"=>"4", "year"=>"2012"}:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess